# EWS SubscribeToPullNotifications does not get new emails

Tags: vb.net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I had the following code written using EWS to subscribe to Pull notifications and read new emails. It was working all fine. All of a sudden it does not read the new emails. Any ideas what could the cause be? And how to resolve it?

```
Imports Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data
Imports System.Threading

Public Class FormTest

Dim subscription As PullSubscription
Dim service As ExchangeService

Private Sub ButtonStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonStart.Click

    service = New ExchangeService
    service.Credentials = New WebCredentials("myusername", "mypassword", "mydomain")
    service.Url = New Uri("https://webmail.mydomain.com/EWS/exchange.asmx")

    subscription = service.SubscribeToPullNotifications(New FolderId() {WellKnownFolderName.Inbox}, 1440, Nothing, EventType.NewMail)

 End Sub

Private Sub ButtonPoll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonPoll.Click
    PollEmails()
End Sub

Private Sub PollEmails()
    Dim events As GetEventsResults = subscription.GetEvents()
    For Each itemEvent As ItemEvent In events.ItemEvents
        Dim message As EmailMessage = EmailMessage.Bind(service, itemEvent.ItemId)
        message.Load()
        ' Do something with 'message'            
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

Basically when I press ButtonPoll events does not contain any new evenets, even though there has been new emails since the ButtonStart was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Heyo!!  I am doing something very similar.  Looks like you have posted this question a month and a half ago so you may have solved it by now, but I wanted to put my initial experiences up here for anyone else that may be looking.  The way I am posting below is a way to get notifications without having to push a poll button.  This may help!  I stripped all my fancy stuff out, as it is always important to learn, but this initial part of it was the most obnoxious part to figure out.

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Security
Imports Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data
Imports System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates

Public Class MainForm

    Private Sub ExecuteButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExecuteButton.Click
        Console.Clear()
        Dim exch As ExchangeService = New ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2)
        exch.Url = New Uri("https://" + ExchangeURLTB.Text + "/EWS/Exchange.asmx")
        exch.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        exch.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(UsernameTB.Text, PasswordTB.Text, DomainTB.Text)
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf ValidateCertificate)
        Dim subscribeStreaming As StreamingSubscription = exch.SubscribeToStreamingNotifications(New FolderId() {WellKnownFolderName.Inbox}, EventType.NewMail, EventType.Created, EventType.Deleted)
        Dim subscribeStreamingConnection = New StreamingSubscriptionConnection(exch, 30)
        subscribeStreamingConnection.AddSubscription(subscribeStreaming)
        AddHandler subscribeStreamingConnection.OnNotificationEvent, AddressOf OnNotificationEvent
        AddHandler subscribeStreamingConnection.OnSubscriptionError, AddressOf OnSubscriptionError
        AddHandler subscribeStreamingConnection.OnDisconnect, AddressOf OnDisconnect
        subscribeStreamingConnection.Open()

        Console.Write("Steaming subscription open")
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnNotificationEvent(sender As Object, args As NotificationEventArgs)
        Dim subscription As StreamingSubscription = args.Subscription
        For Each notification As NotificationEvent In args.Events
            Select Case notification.EventType
                Case EventType.NewMail
                    Console.WriteLine(vbNewLine)
                    Console.WriteLine("-------------Mail created:-------------")
            End Select
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnSubscriptionError(sender As Object, args As SubscriptionErrorEventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub OnDisconnect(sender As Object, args As SubscriptionErrorEventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Function ValidateCertificate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal certificate As X509Certificate, ByVal chain As X509Chain, ByVal sslPolicyErrors As SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean
        'Return True to force the certificate to be accepted.
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out later and let you know.